# Adding a Checkbox to each Pivot Table Row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox, pivot-table

Does anyone know how to automatically add a checkbox to the beginning of each result row in a pivot table in Google Sheets?

On this Google page: https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308622?hl=en, it seems to say that it is possible, but doesn't say how to:

- "Use checkboxes to make Google Sheets more interactive. You can use checkboxes with charts, filters, pivot tables, and formulas."

I would like to allow the user to select one or more rows from the pivot table result, and then have a script run over the rows, doing something with each selected (checked) row.

You could add a checkbox beside the pivot table in a huge number of rows (so there would be a checkbox no matter how long the pivot table is), then allow the pivot table to fill in beside each of these checkboxes, but that would be a brute force approach and look bad.

Here is somewhat of an image of what one of the pivot tables looks like.  I needed to mock it up somewhat to protect the confidentiality, so it doesn't have some of the elements of a Google Sheets pivot table in it, but almost looks like the original.
[image: Pivot Table Example/Mock-up]

What I need to be able to do is add a column to the left with checkboxes, where the user can select any (or all) of the rows.  Then a script would loop over those and move those rows to another sheet and/or perform functions on the rows.

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample images of input and output you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand about the solution for achieving your goal.

Comment: @Tanaike - Thank you for the response and question.  I have modified the question above.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. Is the additional image is the sample input situation? If it's so, can I see the output situation you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike There is no output yet.  When the user selects one or more of those lines above (for example), then a custom script would run (runOnEdit), which looks at each row, finds those where the checkbox = true, and then copies the line to a different sheet/tab where the user can then execute a different script over all of the rows in that sheet to do something - namely contacting each person.

Comment: So, for example given that there would be checkboxes on the example pivot table entries above, and if the user checked Charity Case, Suzy Q, Jo King, & Sammy Now rows, those rows would then be moved (via script) to a new sheet.  The user could perhaps also select rows from a different query/pivot table that would also move to the same other sheet.  Then, the user could go to that sheet, click on a function and have it send an email to all of the customers that are now in that second sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that you cannot provide the sample output situation you expect. From your replying, unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to try to understand about it. When I could correctly understand about your question, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again.